# Does software that has been built for older versions of Ubuntu run on newer versions?

Tags: software-installation, versions, compatibility, backport

On the list of downloads for some software that I want to install they have the options:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

But I am using Ubuntu 20.04. If I download the version for 18.04 will this work on my system? What are things that could go wrong or that I should look out for?

I imagine this is dependent on the particular software that I am installing, so I have contacted the support team, but in general how well does this work? Is it likely that most of the time there will be no issues?

Comment: Basically it depends on whether the software is self-contained or depends on shared libraries. If you specify the software in question, you can get more specific answers.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS only has Qt5 libraries, as Qt4 was removed in 2019 being replaced by Qt5 in 2012 but supported for some time after that. I'm using this as example, so if a requirement of a package requires Qt4, then no it won't work with the Qt5 in later releases. I could mention python2, then .... and go on.. API & ABI's change so you can get *segfault* and other issues using the wrong library, or just errors (depending on language or toolkit/framework being utilized). That's what is handled by package *depends* rules.. which prevent these errors...